# how to get a direct byte buffer from an address location

Tags: java, opencv, bytebuffer, unsafe

In [this opencv example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html), the Mat object has a `nativeObj` field, returning a long that represents the address of the object (i.e `140398889556640`). Because the size of the data within the object is known, I wish to access the contents of the Mat object directly, returning a byte buffer.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: You can't access memory without knowing how much you can safety access.

Comment: Size of the data is not unknown, it is mat.total() * mat.channels()

Comment: Rather than `nativeObj` (which would point to the `cv::Mat` instance, not the pixels), it would seem you want `dataAddr`. Looking at the source code, it gives you value `cv::Mat::data`, which points to the pixel data. Keep in mind that you also have to account for situations where the data is not continuous (usually if the `Mat` represents of ROI of a bigger image).

Comment: @DanMašek. thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the address with a DirectByteBuffer or use Unsafe.

While you can do this, you probably shouldn't. I would explore all other options first.

```
// Warning: only do this if there is no better option

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(128);
    long addr = ((DirectBuffer) bb).address();

    ByteBuffer bb2 = wrapAddress(addr, bb.capacity());

    bb.putLong(0, 0x12345678);
    System.out.println(Long.toHexString(bb2.getLong(0)));
}

static final Field address, capacity;
static {
    try {
        address = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address");
        address.setAccessible(true);
        capacity = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("capacity");
        capacity.setAccessible(true);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public static ByteBuffer wrapAddress(long addr, int length) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    try {
        address.setLong(bb, addr);
        capacity.setInt(bb, length);
        bb.clear();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    return bb;
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of how to wrap the address?

Comment: @zcaudate I have added a simple example. BTW This won't compile on Java 9+, but you can do something similar.

Comment: Exactly what bad thing will happen to me if I do this?

Comment: @barneypitt The use of `DirectBuffer` won't compile on Java 9+. However, there are work arounds. e.g. compile it on Java 8.

Comment: Ah. How I despise Java 9. I think Project Jigsaw is universally loathed except by the folks at Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Unsafe` and want something that works without warnings in Java 9 and is actually portable across JVMs you can use JNIs [NewDirectByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer). This is API and guaranteed to work.

You will need to write some C (or C++) code however and ship a native library with your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tiny framework called "nalloc" which is designed to help developer with memory/pointers manipulations, it could be useful for whatever purposes you are looking for direct memory address accessing.

Also it brings you ability to write your Java program in a C-style, doing memory stuff manually.

Check it out: https://github.com/alaisi/nalloc